# Google is undefined: How to check if google maps script is loaded in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am getting "google is undefined" at times when I load my component containing a map in my React project. The reason seems to be that the google api script is not loading in time when the internet connection is not good enough.

I am loading the maps api script in app.js like so.

```
componentWillMount() {
    const API_KEY = process.env.GOOGLEMAP_API_KEY;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${API_KEY}`;
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    document.head.append(script);
  }
```

Is there a way to check if google maps script has loaded before returning renderApp or use the check somewhere else in the app? I have tried using typeOf google and typeOf google.maps, but they just return undefined.

```
renderApp() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Main />
        </div>
      );
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderApp()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Aside from using the library, react-async-script-loader, how do I check that google maps is available before render a component. React-async-script-loader may be solution, but it would require some major reworking of my map component.

I have found some discussions online but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you just attach a `load` listener to the `script`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a callback param you could pass in the url. It will be called one the async file is loaded.

> When the API is ready, it will call the function specified using the
>   callback parameter.

```
&callback=initMap
```

Example:

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?${API_KEY}&callback=initMap"
```

Comment: Could initMap be defined in app.js? I tried that and the callback was not called. If I have to append another script to index.html, could variables in that script be available globally?

Comment: make it global like `window.initMap = this.yourFunc;` This should help you http://www.klaasnotfound.com/2016/11/06/making-google-maps-work-with-react/

Comment: Thanks, it works. I did come across your solution before, but passed on it since I read that it has SSR issues, but for now it will work since I'm not doing SSR.

Comment: The callback param is not very helpful because it cannot call scoped functions written deep within any framework..

Comment: @vsync you shouldn't have down voted for that, cb is designed like that, the maps lib dont know how ur code is scoped. cb its not defined by me, its exposed by Google, might be Google don't know the it well and did it wrong :\